# AngularJs: Does not update the model after the modifying it through $http transform

Tags: angularjs, data-binding

I need to transform objects coming from $http call to an api. My code adds some fields (functions) to the object coming from the api, here the constructor of this object :

```
 (function () {
     window.TransformedObject = function (obj) {
         var self = this;

         self = {};
         if (obj) {
             self = angular.copy(obj);
         }

         self.hasChanged = function () {
             // return true or false if the object has changed
         }

         return self;
     }

 }());
```

The $http transform code looks like this :

```
 $http({
   url: 'api/...',
   method: 'GET',
   transformResponse: function(value) {
       return new TransformedObject(JSON.parse(value));
   })
 }).success(function(data){
      vm.obj = angular.copy(data);
 });
```

*Note that the `value` in the transformResponse callback is stringified, and need to be parsed to get the object*

All this is working fine, suppose the object coming from the api contains a key called `title`, doing `obj.title = 'some title'` will update the object.

**The problem** :

Binding the `title` field with an input tag will not update the object if the change is coming from the view.

I use a regular `ng-model` to do it:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Title" ng-model="vm.obj.title"/>
```

even using `$rootScope.$watch` will never be triggered if the change is coming from the view aka the input tag.

```
$rootScope.$watch(function () {
            return vm.obj;
        }, function () {
            console.log('watch');
            // this log will never appear in the console
        });
```

Am I doing something wrong, why transforming the object coming from the api is breaking angulars binding ???

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2605-scope-evalasync-vs-timeout-in-angularjs.htm

> Sometimes, in an AngularJS application, you have to explicitly tell
>   AngularJS when to initiate it's $digest() lifecycle (for dirty-data
>   checking). This requirement is typically contained within a Directive;
>   but, it may also be in an asynchronous Service. Most of the time, this
>   can be easily accomplished with the $scope.$apply() method. However,
>   some of the time, you have to defer the $apply() invocation because it
>   may or may not conflict with an already-running $digest phase. In
>   those cases, you can use the $timeout() service; but, I'm starting to
>   think that the $scope.$evalAsync() method is a better option.
>
> ...
>
> Up until now, my approach to deferred-$digest-invocation was to
>   replace the $scope.$apply() call with the $timeout() service (which
>   implicitly calls $apply() after a delay). But, yesterday, I discovered
>   the $scope.$evalAsync() method. Both of these accomplish the same
>   thing - they defer expression-evaluation until a later point in time.
>   But, the $scope.$evalAsync() is likely to execute in the same tick of
>   the JavaScript event loop.

Comment: You are right, adding `$rootScope.$digest();` after returning the object in the transform callback resolved the problem.

Ill check a few more details and mark this as an answer, thanks Amy.